# Jquery Image Slider not showing the third image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create my version of an image slider but it is not working as I want it to be.
I have 3 sample images that should slide from right to left. But it doesn't show up the third image. Please see this [pen](http://codepen.io/ajnoguerra/pen/Cqvik)

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You need to adjust your timings. Check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EIwFe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes :)

First, the delays. You need "adjust" them.
And second, you need to "hide" the element showing, no?

There is a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BlJoG) forked working.. or think so ;)

Comment: Can you explain further the errors with the delay and why should it be adjusted? I need to understand so I'll learn from my mistake :) Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider > img#1').show("fade", 500);
        $('.slider > img#1').delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);

        startSlider();
    });

    function startSlider(){
        count = $(".slider > img").size();  

        loop = setInterval(function(){

            if(sliderNext > count){
                sliderNext = 1;
                sliderInt = 1
            }

            $(".slider > #"+sliderNext).show("slide", {direction: 'right'}, 500).delay(500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);

            sliderInt = sliderNext;
            sliderNext = sliderNext+1;
        },3000)
    }
```